# Contraction mapping with no fixed point

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, fa.functional-analysis

I am interested in constructing the following "counter-example" to the Banach's fixed point theorem.

Let $K=$ {$ g\in L_1: \|g\|=1, g(\cdot)\ge0 $}.
 Clearly, $K$ is not a compact and $K$ is  <s>not</s>   closed.

<s>My</s> A question is: is it possible to construct a [*edit*] *nonexpansive* mapping $f: K\to K$  with no fixed point? (   i.e. a mapping $f$ such that [*edit*] for all $x\neq y\in K$ one has $\|f(x)-f(y)\| <  \|x-y\|$. )

Comment: The Banach contraction mapping theorem only requires the space to be complete, not compact. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem.

Comment: Clearly, this set $K$ is not closed either. Consider g_n(t)=1/n I(0<t<n), then L_1 norm of g_n is 1, however this sequence does not converge to an element of $K$.

Comment: @Oleg: that $g_n$ is not Cauchy, so it does not disprove $K$ closed.  In fact, $K$ is closed (in the $L_1$ metric).

Comment: So what? The sequence does not converge at all. Interpreting $g\ge 0$
as almost sure positivity, the set $K$ is indeed closed and hence complete so that the fixed point theorem applies.

Comment: I've voted to close as "no longer relevant"-- it seems that Pablo already answered the question in his comment.

Comment: To save the question, the OP could ask for a "weak contraction" mapping with no fixed points $f:K\to K$ on the same set $K$ defined above, but now only satisfying $\|f(x)-f(y)\| < \|x -y\|$ for all $x\neq y$ in $K$. (On a compact metric space $K$ such maps do have fixed points). 

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the question and modify it, in order to keep it alive.

Comment: Pietro, what about $f:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}, x \mapsto x^{1/3}+1$?

Comment: (OK, maybe I need to fiddle something near the origin, but I hope the intention is clear.)

Comment: @Yemon: yes, for $K:=\mathbb{R}$ it's OK but I meant the $K$ defined in the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There need not be a fixed point.  First note that by composing with a conditional expectation onto the closed span of indicator functions of disjoint sets it is sufficient to build an example on $W:=\{x\in \ell_1 : x_i \ge 0, \sum x_i =1\}$. Given $x\in W$, define $y=Tx \in W$ by $y_1=0$, $y_2 = x_1/2$, and, for $k\ge 2$, $y_{k+1} = y_k/2 + x_{k+1}/2$. It is obvious that $T$ is nonexpansive. The inequality $\|Tx-Ty\|<\|x-y\|$ when $x\not= y$ follows from the fact that if $x\not= y$ there are coordinates $i$ and $j$ s.t. $x_i<y_i$ and $x_j>y_j$.

Comment: I meant nonexpansive in its usual sense ($\|Tx - Ty \| \le \|x-y\|$) rather than the way Pietro used it.  The main problem was to make the inequality strict when $x\not= y$.